# Spring Security 3.0: GET request after authentication

Tags: php, spring, authentication, spring-security, single-sign-on

I have a Spring Security 3.0 SSO-like built-in Spring application and an external php application that authenticates against my SSO-server.

When a user logs in this application, I would like authenticate him/her in the php application too.

So I did this:

....

```
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost/phpapp/signin");
        httpget.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2");
        httpget.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        httpget.setHeader("Referer", "http://localhost:8080/;jsessionid="+request.getSession().getId());
        httpget.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        httpget.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-gb,en;q=0.5");
        httpget.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        httpget.setHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID="+request.getSession().getId());

        HttpResponse res = httpclient.execute(httpget);

    } finally {
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}
}
```

in the post-authentication handler I created a "GET" request against the signin for the php app.
When it is executed returns in the request-body the "login page" like the user is not logged. Note I used:

```
httpget.setHeader("Referer", "http://localhost:8080/;jsessionid="+request.getSession().getId());
```

as the current authenticated jsessionid.

But if I put the same link: http://localhost/phpapp/signin as normal href link in the page after the authentication and click it works fine.

Any idea why doesn't work the same kind of request in the filter?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely related to the Cookie path. Cookies are tied to the subdomain, domain, path and port so unless both apps are running on http://localhost/phpapp/ you will run into problems. You can try modifying Spring to not set the path or port elements of the cookie i.e. just tie it to localhost.

However I would strongly recommend that you adopt another approach like a true single sign on system, rather that trying to proxy cookies between apps.